# derivative of matrix with respect to vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I need to calculate the derivative of matrix w.r.t. vector.

< Given Equation >

1)
$\mathbb Y = \mathbb A \mathbb X$

,where 
$\mathbb A$: (n$\times$n) matrix 
$\mathbb X$: (n$\times$1) vector.

2)
all elements in $\mathbb A$ and $\mathbb X$ are the function of $z_i$, where
$\mathbb Z = [z_1\ z_2\ \cdots\ z_m]^\top$
In other words,
$\mathbb Y(z)=\mathbb A(z) \mathbb X(z)$

< Problem definition > 
I want to calculate the following partial derivative: $\frac{\partial \mathbb Y}{\partial \mathbb Z}$, which yields a (n$\times$m) matrix
From the general derivation rule for multiplication, it looks like the rule can be expanded (with some modifications) to the matrix/vector version,

$\frac{\partial \mathbb Y}{\partial \mathbb Z}
= 
\frac{\partial (\mathbb A \mathbb X)}{\partial \mathbb Z}
=
\frac{\partial \mathbb A}{\partial \mathbb Z}\mathbb X
+
\mathbb A \frac{\partial \mathbb X}{\partial \mathbb Z}$

However, the above rule is wrong, as you can easily see that the first term's dimension doesn't coincide with (n$\times$m).

I want to calculate the derivation without explicitly calculating all elements in the output $\mathbb Y$.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This formula should work if you're interested in a partial derivative with respect to a single $z_i$.  It will give you a vector, put those vectors into a matrix and you should be OK.

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{\partial\mathbb{A}}{\partial\mathbb{Z}}$?  Since $\mathbb{A}$ is a matrix and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a vector, this should be a $3$-tensor, perhaps?

Comment: Also, check the dimensions, should $\mathbb{A}$ be $n\times m$?

Comment: sorry, I've miswritten the dimensions of $\mathbb A$ and $\mathbb X$: their dimensions should be $n \times n$ and $n \times 1$, for each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula should be correct, when interpreted correctly.

Let's first investigate $\frac{\partial\mathbb{A}}{\partial\mathbb{Z}}$.  $\mathbb{A}$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a vector with $m$ entries.  This means, to specify a derivative, you need three coordinates: the $(i,j)$ for the entry of $\mathbb{A}$ and $k$ for the choice of variable for the derivative.  Therefore, $\frac{\partial\mathbb{A}}{\partial\mathbb{Z}}$ is really a $3$-tensor, and a $3$-tensor times a vector is a matrix.

Similarly, $\frac{\partial\mathbb{X}}{\partial\mathbb{Z}}$ is a matrix because there are two coordinates, $i$ for the entry of $\mathbb{X}$ and $j$ for the choice of derivative.  Hence, $\mathbb{A}\frac{\partial\mathbb{X}}{\partial\mathbb{Z}}$ is a product of matrices, and is itself a matrix.

If you want to figure out the formula a little more explicitly, if we write $\mathbb{A}=(a_{ij}(z))$ and $\mathbb{X}=(x_k(z))$, then
$$
(\mathbb{Y})_i=(\mathbb{A}\mathbb{X})_i=\sum_j a_{ij}(z)x_j(z).
$$
The partial derivative of this with respect to $z_k$ is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}(\mathbb{Y})_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}\sum_j a_{ij}(z)x_j(z)=\sum_j\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}a_{ij}(z)\right)x_j(z)+\sum_ja_{ij}(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}x_j(z).
$$
We can then combine all of these into a vector by dropping the $i$ to get
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbb{Y}}{\partial z_k}=\frac{\partial\mathbb{A}}{\partial z_k}\mathbb{X}+\mathbb{A}\frac{\partial\mathbb{X}}{\partial z_k}.
$$
This gives you the columns of the Jacobian, so they can then be put all together.

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\n{\nabla_z}\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, use the convention wherein lower/upper case letters denote vectors/matrices and rename the problem's variables
$$\{\bb{A,X,Y,X}\} \to \{A,x,y,x\}$$
The gradient calculation with respect to **scalar** components of $z$ obeys the usual product rule
$$\eqalign{
y &= Ax \\
\c{\grad y{z_k}} &= A\gradLR x{z_k} \;+\; \gradLR A{z_k}x \\
}$$
To convert these component gradients into the desired **matrix-valued** gradient, multiply by the corresponding vector $\{e_k\}$ from the standard basis for
${\mathbb R}^{m}$ and sum
$$\eqalign{
\grad yz &= {\large\sum_k} \;\c{\gradLR y{z_k}}e_k^T \\
 &= A\gradLR xz
  \;+\; x^T\!\LR{\grad {A^T}{z}} \\
}$$
The final term is ugly because the quantity in parentheses is a third-order tensor, which is difficult to render in matrix notation, but trivial to write using index notation
$$\eqalign{
\grad{y_i}{z_j} &= {\large\sum_k}\;
A_{ik}\gradLR{x_k}{z_j} \;+\; x_k\gradLR{A_{ik}}{z_j} \\
\\
}$$
A common technique to side-step the tensor issue is to
vectorize the $A$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
a &= \vecc A \\
y &= Ax \\
dy &= A\;dx + dA\;x \\
 &= A\;dx \;+\; \LR{x^T\otimes I} da \\
\grad yz &= A\gradLR xz \;+\; \LR{x^T\otimes I}\gradLR az \\
}$$
where $(\otimes)$ denotes the Kronecker product
and $I\in{\bb R}^{n\times n}\,$ is the identity matrix.

This puts everything in terms of familiar *vector-by-vector* gradients.

Answer (score 1):

Write $y(z) = A(z)x(z)$. We can approach the computation of the linear map $Dy(z) : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ using the Frechet derivative. For $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ small, we have
$$A(z + v) = A(z) + DA(z)v + o(v),$$
$$x(z + v) = x(z) + Dx(z)v + o(v).$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
y(z + v) &= (A(z) + DA(z)v)(x(z) + Dx(z)v) + o(v) \\
&= A(z)x(z) + A(z)Dx(z)v + (DA(z)v)x(z) + o(v).
\end{align}
Thus
$$Dy(z)v = A(z)Dx(z)v + (DA(z)v)x(z).$$
The $j$th column of $Dy(z)$ is therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z_j}(z) &= Dy(z)e_j \\
&= A(z)Dx(z)e_j + (DA(z)e_j)x(z) \\
&= A(z)\frac{\partial x}{\partial z_j}(z) + \frac{\partial A}{\partial z_j}(z)x(z).
\end{align}
It actually does look identical to the product rule! This is no coincidence since the proof of the above rule was identical to the proof of the product rule.